# How to use dynamoDB batchWriteItem with nodejs sdk?

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb

I have a use case where I need to perform a batch_write operation on dynamodb. I referred [this](https://vin0d.medium.com/dynamodb-batch-write-nodejs-f2a9d0d7d740) article which has a good solution for similar use case. I implemented it with few cleanup in my code and it works as expected.

```
const _ = require('lodash');

// helper methods

async function asyncForEach(array, cb) {
  await Promise.all(array.map(async (item) => {
    await cb(item, array);
  }));
}

function to(promise) {
  return promise.then((data) => [null, data])
    .catch((err) => [err]);
}
const call = function (params) {
  return dynamoDb.batchWriteItem(params).promise();
};
async function batchWrite25(arrayOf25, tableName) {
  // 25 is as many as you can write in one time
  const itemsArray = [];
  _.forEach(arrayOf25, (item) => {
    itemsArray.push({
      PutRequest: {
        Item: item,
      },
    });
  });
    const params = {
        RequestItems: {
        [tableName]: itemsArray,
        },
    };

  await to(call(params));
}
async function batchWrite(itemArray, tableName) {
  let mainIndex = 0;
  let subIndex = 0;
  let arrayOf25 = [];
  const arrayLength = itemArray.length;
  await asyncForEach(itemArray, async (item) => {
    arrayOf25.push(item);
    subIndex += 1;
    mainIndex += 1;

    // 25 is as many as you can write in one time
    if (subIndex % 25 === 0 || mainIndex === arrayLength) {
      await to(batchWrite25(arrayOf25, tableName));
      subIndex = 0; // reset
      arrayOf25 = [];
    }
  });
}

module.exports = {
  batchWrite,
};
```

However, the code looks a bit complicated here with so many callbacks involved. Is there a cleaner way of writing the same thing without using -- `call` or `asyncForEach` or `to` methods  ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one simple way to batch the items:

```
const BATCH_MAX = 25;

const batchWrite = async (items, table_name) => {
  const BATCHES = Math.floor((items.length + BATCH_MAX - 1) / BATCH_MAX);

  for (let batch = 0; batch < BATCHES; batch++) {
    const itemsArray = [];

    for (let ii = 0; ii < BATCH_MAX; ii++) {
      const index = batch * BATCH_MAX + ii;

      if (index >= items.length) break;

      itemsArray.push({
        PutRequest: {
          Item: items[index],
        },
      });
    }

    const params = {
      RequestItems: {
        [table_name]: itemsArray,
      },
    };

    console.log("Batch", batch, "write", itemsArray.length, "items");
    await dynamodb.batchWriteItem(params).promise();
  }
};
```

To make the entire process asynchronous, you can convert this function to return an array of promises and later call `Promise.all(promises)` on that array. For example:

```
const batchWrite = (items, table_name) => {
  const promises = [];
  const BATCHES = Math.floor((items.length + BATCH_MAX - 1) / BATCH_MAX);

  for (let batch = 0; batch < BATCHES; batch++) {
    // same code as above here ...
    promises.push(dynamodb.batchWriteItem(params).promise());
  }

  return promises;
};
```

Comment: await inside a for loop makes it synchronous. how to make this asynchronous ?

Comment: Updated answer to accumulate individual promises.

Answer (score 0):

A much cleaner way using lodash that worked for me is listed below. Hope this helps somone.

```
batchWrite=async ()=> {
    const batchSplitArr=_.chunk(this.dynamoPayload,25); //dynamoPayload has the entire payload in the desired format for dynamodb insertion.
    await Promise.all(
        batchSplitArr.map(async (item) => {
            const params = {
            RequestItems: {
              [this.tableName]: item,
            },
          };
            await this.dynamoDb.batchWriteItem(params).promise();
        })
      );
  };
```

Comment: Note that this results in a slightly different outcome. Instead of a single `RequestItems` array of items targeting the table, this lodash solution results in multiple `RequestItems`, one per item, each targeting the same table. This might impact performance under the hood, unless DynamoDB merges them.

Comment: works as expected.